# How to read a script file from a repo in Yaml Pipeline in azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

I have a repository where I have a powershell(.ps1) file which i would like to call in one of the stage of my Yaml Pipeline. I am trying the following way but i get the error as *"[error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/vsts/work/1/s/_DevOpsScripts/ReleaseNoteScripts/abc.ps1'"*

Would like to know What is the correct way of calling the powershell script .

Here is what I am doing now

```
name: $(SourceBranchName)_$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)
trigger:
  - master

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: DevOpsScripts
    type: git
    name: XeThru/DevOpsScripts
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
          - master


- stage: PublishSignalFlowNotebooks
    dependsOn: SignalFlow
    jobs:
      - job: SignalFlow_ReleaseNoteBook    
        steps:
          - checkout: DevOpsScripts
          - task: PowerShell@2
            displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
            inputs:
                targetType: filePath
                filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_DevOpsScripts/ReleaseNoteScripts/abc.ps1
                arguments: '-WId $(NoteBookArtifactDirectory) -ClientID $(clientId) -ClientSecret $(clientSecret) -RDname $(Release.DefinitionName) -RName $(Release.ReleaseName) -RReqFor $(Release.RequestedFor) -RRId $(Release.ReleaseId) -NbId $(NotebookId) -SPid $(SharePointSiteID) -LibId $(LibraryID) -AzDevToken $(AzureDevOpsPersonalAccessToken)'
```

On Debugging I get this:

```
Directory: D:\a\1\s


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
d-----        3/11/2021   6:03 PM                ReleaseNoteScripts                                                    
-a----        3/11/2021   6:03 PM           1319 README.md                                                             


    Directory: D:\a\1\s\ReleaseNoteScripts


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
-a----        3/11/2021   6:03 PM           5341 UploadInSharePoint.ps1                                                
-a----        3/11/2021   6:03 PM          13779 abc.ps1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following step to debug the actual checkout location after the `checkout` task, before the `PowerShell@2` task:

```yaml
- pwsh: |
    Get-ChildItem $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) -Recurse
  name: DebugCheckout
  displayName: Debug script checkout
```

This will generate probably a ton of output, but it should give you an idea of where your scripts are actually located once checked out. I'm guessing it could be something as simple as not needing the `_` in the path.

Comment: on debugging i get the file name and location but not sure, how do i access it. check the result of debugging in question

Comment: ok i see i added an extra folder in there. thanks.